# Hide view every 5 seconds with postDelayed

Tags: android

**PROBLEM**

I have a `horizontalListView` that is showing user all the images loaded to `ViewPager`. Its situated on the bottom of the screen.
What I want to do is for `horizontalListView` to hide when its not being used for more then 5 sec.

How it should work:

- User taps screen `horizontalListView` appears
- User scrolls, selects do stuff on `horizontalListView` and its blocking threads to be fired
- After 5 sec of doing nothing on `horizontalListView`, it disappears

How its working right now:

- User taps screen `horizontalListView` appears
- User scrolls, selects ect. and `postDelayed` is getting fired making my `horizontalListView` dissappear.

**CODE**

**HorizontalListView and Runnable**

```
    horizontalListView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            hideViewHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
            hideViewHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,5*1000);
            return true;
        }
    });

    mRunnable = new StoppableRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void stoppableRun() {
            hideAnimation();
        }
    };
```

**TapListener that is set on Image responsible for showing horizontalListView**

```
  private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        hListView.clearAnimation();
        if (((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) hListView.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin < 0) {
            expandAnimation();
            hideViewHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,5*1000);
        } else {
            hideAnimation();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem myself.

**FIX**

The main reason why my `onTouchListener` did not work as intended was that it had not been triggered at all. `OnClickListener` inside `horizontalListView` adapter was consuming the trigger.

Now I am passing the info that the click occurred inside `onClickListener` and do all the things in different method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check inside the listener for the MotionEvent.ACTION_UP or MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL to only trigger the runnable after them.

Your current code is posting the runnable on any event, but you want to do it only when the user has stopped using the view.

BTW: If you return true from the TouchListener it means that you have consumed the event and the event chain will stop. Most likely the ScrollView will not even scroll, since the event will not be propagated to it.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it does not fix my problem.
Main problem here is that inside `TapListener` I need to run `postDelayed` because there might be a situation in which user will not interact with the `hirozontalListView`. This is the main reason why my code is not working as intended. The trigger is delayed and its not getting removed by `removeCallbacks` inside `touchListener`.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to see that you fixed it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this..

```
   yourScreenLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (horizontalListView.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                horizontalListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (horizontalListView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                            horizontalListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }, 5000);
            } else {
                horizontalListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: That won't help me mate the problem is not with showing/hiding the view  but with how threads works. Thanks for effort tho.

Comment: If you find this postDelayed functionality helpful then upvote pls..@JakubW

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of you problem might be calling `removeCallbacks` before `postDelayed`. 
The thread itself is fired after u clear the queue.

Comment: As far as I know `removeCallbacks` should clear my whole queue.
I use it like that intentionally. What I need to do is to clear the queue and refresh my thread with new 5 sec delay. Every single use of `horizontalListView` should trigger refresh of the delay so it wont disappear mid-use.